# Get column using fixed index?

Tags: java, database

When writing a program to fetch records from database, the code may look like the following:

```
private static final int IDX_A = 1;
private static final int IDX_B = 2;
....

resultSet.getInt(IDX_A);
resultSet.getInt(IDX_B);
....
```

If we have a lot of columns to fetch, we will have too many indexes. So another implementation is:

```
int idx = 0;
resultSet.getInt(++idx);
resultSet.getInt(++idx);
....
```

For speed consideration, I think the first one is better. But for maintenance, I think the latter one is better.

Which one is better if we have a lot of columns? Thanks.

Comment: I would almost certainly go for the latter.

Comment: Isn't getting values by column name better?

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can completely forget the speed consideration: you're calling a database, so the few extra microseconds spent in your code won't matter at all.

My preferred solution would be the following:

```
private static final String COLUMN_A = "ColumnA";
private static final String COLUMN_B = "ColumnB";

resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_A);
resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_B);
```

This avoids bugs getting introduced when your query changes and columns are added to the select clause.

Even better, use JPA.